# Compiling FastCGIWrap fails on slackware (nginx cgi support)

Tags: nginx, cgi, slackware, fcgi

I'm currently trying to get nginx to work with cgit which uses cgi. 
I know nginx doesn't support cgi directly but it appears you can support it indirectly via [FastCGIWrap](http://nginx.localdomain.pl/wiki/FcgiWrap).

The link above is pretty self explanatory but I'm having a problem with compiling the program. What I've done so far:

1. Installed [libfcgi-2.4.0](http://slackware.cs.utah.edu/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/libf/libfcgi/libfcgi_2.4.0.orig.tar.gz)
2. `cd fcgiwrap && autoconf -i`
3. When I run `./configure` I get this output

   ```
   checking for gcc... gcc
   checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
   checking whether the C compiler works... yes
   checking whether we are cross compiling... no
   checking for suffix of executables...
   checking for suffix of object files... o
   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
   checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
   checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
   checking for FCGX_Init in -lfcgi... yes
   checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
   checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
   checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
   checking for ANSI C header files... yes
   checking for sys/types.h... yes
   checking for sys/stat.h... yes
   checking for stdlib.h... yes
   checking for string.h... yes
   checking for memory.h... yes
   checking for strings.h... yes
   checking for inttypes.h... yes
   checking for stdint.h... yes
   checking for unistd.h... yes
   checking fcntl.h usability... yes
   checking fcntl.h presence... yes
   checking for fcntl.h... yes
   checking limits.h usability... yes
   checking limits.h presence... yes
   checking for limits.h... yes
   checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
   checking for string.h... (cached) yes
   checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
   checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
   checking for _Bool... yes
   checking for pid_t... yes
   checking for size_t... yes
   checking for ssize_t... yes
   checking vfork.h usability... no
   checking vfork.h presence... no
   checking for vfork.h... no
   checking for fork... yes
   checking for vfork... yes
   checking for working fork... yes
   checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
   checking whether lstat dereferences a symlink specified with a trailing slash... yes
   checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
   checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
   checking for strchr... yes
   checking for strdup... yes
   checking for strrchr... yes
   checking for dup2... yes
   checking for putenv... yes
   checking for select... yes
   checking for setenv... yes
   checking for strerror... yes
   configure: creating ./config.status
   config.status: creating Makefile
   config.status: WARNING:  'Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
   config.status: error: cannot find input file: config.h.in
   ```

After this I can't do `make -s && make -s install` because it can't find `config.h.in`.
Is there another way to install this on slackware 12.2 or is there any package of it or this program is meant only for Debian/Ubuntu like distros?

Edit: 
`automake` returns:

```
Useless use of /d modifier in transliteration operator at /usr/share/automake-1.10/Automake/Wrap.pm line 60.
configure.ac: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found.
configure.ac: You should verify that configure.ac invokes AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE,
configure.ac: that aclocal.m4 is present in the top-level directory,
configure.ac: and that aclocal.m4 was recently regenerated (using aclocal).
automake: no `Makefile.am' found for any configure output
```

Comment: Try to re-unpack the distro but this time omit `autoconf` step.

Comment: I'd usually do that but in this case, if you download the archive, you'll see there's no `./configure` script. You can't do `make && make install` because it fails with `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Comment: then, try doing `automake` before `autoconf`.

Comment: Question updated with the result..

Comment: have you tried `autoreconf -i`?

Comment: Yes I have. But I forgot to put it in the question. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: Please double-check: in the question you wrote `autoconf -i` while the instructions ask for `autoREconf -i`. If yes, then I'd suggest to reach Grzesiek, the author of the package, for his insight.

Comment: `autoreconfig` definitely did the work! Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Autoreconf](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/autoreconf-Invocation.html)'s option -i should generate missing autotool files using library defaults.